# シェルスクリプトをCtl+cで止める方法

Tags: shellscript

```
#!/bin/sh
param_list=("param1" "param2" "param3")
for param in "${param_list[@]}"
do
  python sample.py $param
done
```

以上のように、ファイルにコマンドライン引数を渡してfor文で実行した際に、Ctl+c一回ではループから抜けられません。どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: /bin/sh の実体は何になりますか? `readlink`(1) が使える環境であれば、`readlink /bin/sh` で調べるのが簡単だと思います。bash あるいは ksh (mksh, pdksh ではなく AT&T ksh) ではないでしょうか? 手元で調べた限りでは、シェル実装 (bash と ksh) の問題です。dash や zsh など、ほかのシェル実装では問題ありません。

Comment: Ctrl+c一回では抜けられないということは、何回かCtrl+cすれば抜けられるということですか？それなら実はもっと単純に`python sample.py $param || exit`でも良いのでは？

Answer (score 1):

PythonインタプリタがデフォルトでSIGINTシグナルをトラップしてPython内の例外として扱っているからではないでしょうか。

OSのデフォルトの動作にするには、Pythonスクリプト中でハンドラにSIG_DFLを設定するとか。

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

Comment: Ctrl+C を受けた tty はプロセスグループに SIGINT シグナルを送るので、Python プロセスだけでなく、sh プロセスにもシグナルは送られます。ざっくり調べた限りでは、この問題は sh (恐らく bash) の問題であり、Python プロセスが SIGINT を受けて終了するのが速ければ問題を回避できる可能性はありますが、根本的な解決にはなりません。

Comment: 本当だ、dashだとPython側で仕掛けしなくても終了しますね。

Answer (score 0):

シェルスクリプト側で trap を使うとか。

```
trap 'exit 1' INT
```

Comment: bash-4.3.42 で試しました。
bash の問題なのかどうかはわかりませんが、この実装において、trap ハンドラで(exit 1 以外でも)ループを抜けるのは悪いアイデアでしょうか？

Comment: 悪くないと思います。SIGINT で終了したことを明示するなら、`trap 'exit 130' INT` がよりよいでしょう。(128 + SIGINT の整数値)

Answer (score 0):

シェルスクリプトで終了する関数を作成し、trapを実行しましょう

```sh
function force_exit () {
    # 何か終了処理
    exit 1
}

trap 'force_exit' 1 2 3 15
```